# Ldap template authentication with user group

Tags: spring, ldap

I stuck with spring ldaptemplate authentication method returning zero count while using the group string, the string like below.

CN=Jirra-Acdolite-DG,OU=Jira Security Group,OU=Apps Security Group,OU=Security Groups,OU=Global,OU=BT,DC=barcadero,DC=com

We are trying with ldap user group with following code.

```
    try {
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();

        ctxSrc.setUrl(url);
        // ctxSrc.setBase(base);
        ctxSrc.setUserDn(ManagerDn);
        ctxSrc.setPassword(ManagerPassword);

        ctxSrc.setReferral("follow");

        ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet();

        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

        System.out.println("50");
        ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        AndFilter andfilter = new AndFilter().and(new EqualsFilter("objectCategory", "person"))
                .and(new EqualsFilter("objectClass", "user")).and(new EqualsFilter(SearchAttributes, userDn))
                .and(new EqualsFilter("memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:",
                        "CN=Jirra-Acdolite-DG,OU=Jira Security Group,OU=Apps Security Group,OU=Security Groups,OU=Global,OU=BT,DC=barcadero,DC=com
```

"));
            System.out.println(andfilter);
            if (!ldapTemplate.authenticate(base, andfilter.encode(), password, new AuthenticationErrorCallback() {
                public void execute(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("exception");
                }
            })) {
                System.out.println("False\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Success");
            }

But we always getting the False value along with Group string. If any help on same thanks.

THe error message showing like below.

Feb 15, 2018 12:32:52 AM org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate authenticate
INFO: No results found for search, base:
CN=Jirra-Acdolite-DG,OU=Jira Security Group,OU=Apps Security Group,OU=Security Groups,OU=Global,OU=BT,DC=barcadero,DC=com

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to authenticate a user under a specific group , try to get all users under that group and make a search in it ( i done it like that)

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:", groupDN));
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectClass", "user"));

return ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, filter.encode(), new ContractAttributeMapperJSON());
}
```